# How do I use cookies from Indy to initiate TWebBrowser cookies?

Tags: delphi, session-cookies, indy10

I use `TIdHttp` with a cookie manager when logging in to my server.

Later in the program, the user may activate a `TWebBrowser` to do searching in the database that the program produces data for, after uploading results.

Since the user is already authorized as a valid user, I want to let the user get into the page directly.

The PHP script sets some cookies, in addition the traditional phpsessid.

How can I transfer the cookies from my Indy component into the `TWebBrowser` so that the user can continue in the same session?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14826727/33732, which is the inverse of this question.

Answer (score 4):

`TWebBrowser` is a wrapper around Microsoft Internet Explorer, which uses its own cookie management system.  There is no API available to insert user-defined cookies into Microsoft's cookie store.  However, Microsoft saves cookies in a special folder that you can locate programambly using `SHGetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_COOKIES)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Cookies)`.  You can then manually save Indy's cookies to files in Microsoft's cookie file format, which you can find documented online in various websites if you Google around.

Comment: Is the sess_id from the Indy session also valid if inserted this way into tWebbrowser?

Comment: The values of the cookies are dictated by the webserver, not by Indy. Cookies do have other attributes (domain, path, etc) that control a cookie's behavior, and those values have to be carried over to IE as well.  I don't know anyone who has actually done all of this in practice, but in theory it should be possible.